# How to fire mouseover event with specific clientX and clientY parameter values in Selenium IDE?

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

I am trying to write a test that enters some text into a [Froala JS editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) instance, in Selenium IDE 2.9.1 (Firefox 45).  I'm not able to determine any way to specify the `clientX` and `clientY` parameters to this event, which apparently Froala code is relying on to make the editor function properly.

If I use Selenium IDE's `mouseOver` command, there is no ability to specify these coordinates (it does not have a corresponding `mouseOverAt` command, as some other mouse events do).  Using simply `fireEvent` command, with `mouseover` as the value, I cannot specify any parameters to that native JS event.

How can I send a `mouseOver` event to a particular element, with these coordinates, in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no good way to specify mouse coordinates using javascript. Since Selenium IDE is based on Javascript most probably it is impossible to set mouseover for specific coordinates. At least that's what I think.

But there is the way to change text in the Froala element anyway:

```
open    | https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor
getEval | window.document.evaluate( "//*[@id='froala-editor']//div[@class='fr-element fr-view']//h1",window.document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue.innerHTML='CROCODILE!!! ARRR!!!'
```

It seems pretty complex but adding a text is even more complex.

```
open    | https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor
getEval | var addedH1 = window.document.createElement("h1"); addedH1.innerHTML = 'Added text'; window.document.evaluate( "//*[@id='froala-editor']//div[@class='fr-element fr-view']//h1/..",window.document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue.appendChild(addedH1);
```

That is the only way I can suggest I hope it will help.